# rx-java2: how to safely invoke flatMapSingle

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am struggling with rx-java2. Basically, I cannot safely "escape" from `Maybe` to `Single` and continue the logic flow for the rest items.
So here's my simplified code, demonstrating my question:

```
  public Flowable<Long> run() {
    //let's assume this is my "input" data
    List<UserTask> userTasks;

    return Single.just(userTasks)
        .flatMapPublisher(Flowable::fromIterable)
         // userRepository.getUser returns a Maybe<User>
        .map((UserTask ut) -> userRepository.getUser(ut.getName())
                //search for user
                //if not found, return a dummy user object
                .defaultIfEmpty(User.newBuilder().build())
                //leave dummy user objects only
                .filter((User u) -> u.getName() == null)
                //for each dummy user object return a corresponding user task
                .map(u -> ut)
        )
        .flatMapSingle(Maybe::toSingle)
        .flatMap((UserTask mt) -> {
          // return user related to user task, implementation does not matter
          return Flowable.just(User.newBuilder().build());
        })
        .flatMapSingle(this::saveUser);
  }

  private Single<Long> saveUser(User u) {
    return userRepository.saveUser(m).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
  }
```

I tried to provide types where needed to ease the understanding.
The problem here is that in case the `Maybe` is empty, this line (I guess) `.flatMapSingle(Maybe::toSingle)` throws an exception `NoSuchItemException` and the flow execution terminates. Is it possible to improve my code so that if `Maybe` value is absent, the flow skips this item and goes on?

Please let me know if there's some missing details, I'll provide them.

Comment: Have you had a look at `switchIfEmpty`?

Comment: @vguzzi for what? to return `Maybe.error(new SomeException())` which would stop the execution?

Comment: Try putting another filter after the map to filter out absent Maybe returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you chose this convoluted set of operators. Try this:

```java
public Flowable<Long> run() {
    //let's assume this is my "input" data
    List<UserTask> userTasks;

    return 
    Flowable.fromIterable(userTasks)
     // userRepository.getUser returns a Maybe<User>
    .flatMapMaybe((UserTask ut) -> userRepository.getUser(ut.getName())
            .defaultIfEmpty(User.newBuilder().build())
            .filter((User u) -> u.getName() == null)
            .map(u -> ut)
    )
    .map((UserTask mt) -> {
      // return user related to user task, implementation does not matter
      return User.newBuilder().build();
    })
    .flatMapSingle(this::saveUser);
}

private Single<Long> saveUser(User u) {
   return userRepository.saveUser(m).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#using-an-overload-with-the-desired-type) details the type conversions between reactive types.

Comment: thank you. Maybe I overlooked something, but I cannot apply the last line (i.e. `.flatMapSingle(...)`, it gives me type errors

Comment: Please provide more details and the code that is actually representative of your situation.

Comment: sorry, just figured it out why it happens. In my code this thingie: `// return user related to user task, implementation does not matter` actually returns a `Flowable<User>`, not just `User`, therefore your example doesn't work for me (but it is a great source for learning I must admit!)

Comment: Why do you have a `just` there? It indicates the code above it can be executed synchronously thus `map` is a more appropriate transformation there.

Comment: because there some `Flowable<..>` computation is performed, which should be taken care of when constructing a `User`

Comment: Okay, what do you expect me to do?

Comment: nothing, I tuned your version to satisfy my needs. Thank you again for your time.